# Static IP config no longer persistent in CentOS6

Tags: linux, centos, ip

I was messing around with KVM in CentOS 6.3 when I noticed I was having problems with the IP address of my principle network connection (eth0). I backed out my bridge
and restored the network-script file for eth0 but the IP address still goes missing after reboot. At this point I have to return to the console and restart the "network" service. The address will then be restored but only until the next boot.
I have turned off NetworkManager but this does not seem to help. The ifcfg is below:

```
*DEVICE=eth0 
ONBOOT=yes 
BOOTPROTO=static 
NM_Controlled=no 
IPADDR=192.168.17.49 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 
GATEWAY=192.168.17.1    
DEFAULT=yes DNS1=67.69.184.212*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked: `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/messages`, or `/var/log/daemon.log` for the relevant information?  If so please post it.

Comment: What's the `*` before `DEVICE`, was it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

`At this point I have to return to the console and restart the "network" service.`

The reason is clear through your description, your `network` service wasn't started automatically, so do a `chkconfig --level 2345 network on` will fix your problem.

P.S: I just saw a `*` before the DEVICE, so that could be a problem as well (if it's not a typo)

Comment: ...or something is messing with the network stack on boot, such as a DHCP agent.